# Importing contacts from gmail, yahoo, hotmail facebook and twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, yahoo

I need to import the contacts from gmail, yahoo hotmail and facebook and many more, I am aware of the google api's. Is there any libraries which allows me to import all the contacts or should dirt my hands writing the codes using all the api's.

And also I have to embed html code in the email and I have to send it across my friends.

I am using javascript at the front end and servlets at the back end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My need is same as you, so I find these links
[sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber)
[code.google.com/p/contactlistimporter](http://code.google.com/p/contactlistimporter)
[www.gigya.com](http://www.gigya.com)
[www.plaxo.com](http://www.plaxo.com)
[www.cloudsponge.com](http://www.cloudsponge.com)
[www.svetlozar.net](http://www.svetlozar.net)
[www.openinviter.com](http://www.openinviter.com)
[opensource.brickred.com/socialauthdemo](http://opensource.brickred.com/socialauthdemo)
However, I like to make my hands dirty ;)

Comment: Does anyone have any preference/feedback over which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can check oneall. It provide 20+ social networking website API.

http://www.oneall.com/